# import directory.file as XYZ

Tags: python

I'm working in google colab and trying to run a python file (let's call it B) and get this:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "run_sem_seg_penumothorax.py", line 5, in <module> import step.make_sem_seg_lables_pneumothorax as make_sem_seg_lables_pneumothorax`

I am in a mother directory, let's call it A. This is how it's organised:

1. I'm in cd A
2. -B is a file that I'm trying to run
3. ```
     -STEP is a directory in A
   ```
4. ```
            make_sem..... is a file in directory A/STEP
   ```

For some reason my colab notebook doesn't pull this file from the step folder and I don't know how to resolve it. I was trying to edit my file B and do something like this:

`import 'google drive directory:/step.make_sem_seg_lables_pneumothorax' as make_sem_seg_lables_pneumothorax ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'step.make_sem_seg_lables_pneumothorax'`

Sadly, didn't work.

1. Do I have to edit the file?
2. If so, how to do it?
3. I see in all githubs that they name files this way mother_folder.daughter_file so I guess it works in their cases. Why doesn't it work for me?

Thank you,
Joanna

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused trying to understand how the folders are organized. Is this how the directory structure looks?

```
A
├── B.py
└── STEP
    └── make_sem.py
```

---

EDIT:
Ok, now what version of python are you running? If it is less than Python3.3, you'll need to add an **input**.py file in the STEP directory like this: (see [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for))

```
A
├── B.py
└── STEP
    ├── __init__.py
    └── make_sem.py
```

Comment: Yes, precisely that way